# KeyError when reading from Excel data into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file with two sheets and I am trying to read both of them into a dataframe as in the code below. However, I get the error

```
KeyError: "['months_to_maturity' 'asset_id' 'orig_iss_dt' 'maturity_dt' 'pay_freq_cd'\n 'coupon' 'closing_price'] not in index"
```

in the line

```
return df[['months_to_maturity', 'asset_id', 'orig_iss_dt', 'maturity_dt' , 'pay_freq_cd', 'coupon', 'closing_price']]
```

in the `SecondExcelFileReader()` function. However, both sheets have the headers

```
asset_id    orig_iss_dt maturity_dt  pay_freq_cd    coupon  closing_price   months_to_maturity
```

I return `df` as follows as that is the order in which I want the columns.

```
def ExcelFileReader():
    xls = pd.ExcelFile('D:/USDataRECENTLY.xls')
    df = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0])
    return df[['months_to_maturity', 'asset_id', 'orig_iss_dt', 'maturity_dt' , 'pay_freq_cd', 'coupon', 'closing_price']]


def SecondExcelFileReader():
    xls = pd.ExcelFile('D:/USDataRECENTLY.xls')
    df = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[1])
    return df[['months_to_maturity', 'asset_id', 'orig_iss_dt', 'maturity_dt' , 'pay_freq_cd', 'coupon', 'closing_price']]

def mergingdataframes():
    df1 = ExcelFileReader()
    df2 = SecondExcelFileReader()
    return pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

**Edit**: This Excel file was exported from Sybase Oracle SQL Developer and hence the first sheet came already with the titles. I just copied and pasted the second sheet with the same titles. Also, I am only having the issue with the second sheet.

Sheet 1:
[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 2:
[image: Sheet 2]

Comment: You do not get the issue for first sheet?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I don't have an issue with the first sheet. I do have to explain that this Excel file was exported from Sybase Oracle SQL Developer and hence the first sheet came already with the titles. I just copied and pasted the 2nd sheet with the titles though.

Comment: Can you show the second sheet and first sheet (maybe a screenshot)?

Comment: First look at the output `df` before selecting a subset of the columns. If it looks good, try to select each column individually and see if you get a KeyError. If so, it could be something silly like extra whitespace in one of the column names.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I've added some screenshots to the Question.

Comment: Were you able to print the `df` as Joe pointed and did you see the results of it?

Comment: @user131983 Why are you reading those files in that manner? Why not use `pandas.read_excel`? This method includes a number of arguments to control the parsing including a `sheetname` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def ExcelFileReader():
    xls = pd.ExcelFile('D:/USDataRECENTLY.xls')
    sheet_num = xls.sheet_names.index(xls.sheet_names[0])
    df = pd.read_excel('D:/USDataRECENTLY.xls',sheetname=sheet_num)
    return df[['months_to_maturity', 'asset_id', 'orig_iss_dt', 'maturity_dt' ,'pay_freq_cd', 'coupon', 'closing_price']]
```

Alternatively in this case instead of `sheetname = xls.sheet_names[0]` you could use `sheetname=0`

Looks like your issue is that your second sheetname is "Sheet1" and based on ExcelParser documentation "Sheet1" means the first sheet, but in your case it's the second sheet.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html

A better implementation would be:

```
def mergingdataframes():
    mergedf= pd.concat(pd.read_excel('D:/USDataRECENTLY.xls', sheetname=[0,1]))
    mergedf.index = mergedf.index.droplevel(0)# need this to drop dict keys
    return mergedf
```